# Cross domain conversion tracking where DOMAIN B is a third party website

Tags: cross-domain, tracking

I will break it down into different steps.

- User arrives to "DOMAIN A" from an advertisement.
- We have "DOMAIN A" where people can select membership options.
- User selects that they want to sign up, this directs them to "DOMAIN B", which is a third party booking website.
- The User finished the process on "DOMAIN B"

Question: Is it possible to track the conversion action that happens on "DOMAIN B" where we don't really have access to?

We have tried the general Meta pixel and GTM tagging options but we stucked in here because "DOMAIN B" is litteraly another booking service where we don't have access.

Comment: Unless that other service explicitly provides you with a way to do that - no. You can not insert your own tracking code into other websites without their help. And whether it might communicate the status of the operation back to your site in some way, we can't tell from this rudimentary explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have able to put Google Analytics tracking code on both the website then you just need to add Domain B under configure your domain in Data Streams settings and conversion automatically get attributed to source it comes to Domain A

[image]